# Чи є в нас фразеологізм для випадку, коли людина дарує щось, а потім забирає подарунок назад?

Tags: фразеологізми

Якщо хтось дарує подарунок, а потім забирає його назад, то якби це можна було назвати. У американців для цього є термін *indian giver*.

Також цікаво, як можна назвати випадок чи людину, яка краде щось, використовує, а потім повертає. У американців для цього є термін подібний вище згаданому - *indian taker*.

Comment: Сумніваюсь, що є щось подібне. Тут і так грубо, а якщо під наші реалії, то тут ще й політичний відтинок...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Схоже, що такого фразеологізму немає. Принаймі, широкому колу він не відомий.

Так склалось в українців, що відбирати подароване не прийнято, і засуджується суспільною думкою.
У підтвердження, є прислів'я:

> Силою не дають,— силою віднімають. Подарунок назад не беруть.
>   *<sub>//Наприклад в: Українські народні прислів'я та приказки. Дожовтневий період / Упоряд., вступ. ст. В. Бобкова; Упоряд. Й. Багмут, А. Й. Багмут. — Київ: Держлітвидав України, 1963. — [сторінка 314](//books.google.com/books?id=7s_YAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%8E+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%8E+%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%8C%22).</sub>*